# Troubleshooting varien_Io_sftp() to transfer over SFTP from remote host

Tags: php, magento, sftp

***Update at the bottom!***

We've written a script for Magento that reaches out to a third party remote SFTP host and grabs files to process locally.

When we run our script and pull from our remote test server everything runs fine. The file is copied to a local import directory and the import runs as it should. The order status changes to complete.

When we attempt to run the same test connecting and pulling the file from the remote SFTP host the file isn't copied and the process stops there.

Our print statements from the remote SFTP host are showing a successful connection, change of directory and listing of files.

```
<?php
class My_Import_Model_myfileimport
{
    public function __construct(){}

    /**
     * Public method that is called to execute the file import.
     */
    public function run()
    {
        if (Mage::getStoreConfig('file_processing/ifile_status/enabled') == 1):
            //Instantiate the FTP object
            $sftpDumpFile = new Varien_Io_Sftp();

            //Try connecting to the ftp source via sftp
            try {

                $sftpDumpFile->open(
                    array(
                        'host'      => Mage::getStoreConfig('file_processing/ifile_ftp/host'),
                        'username'  => Mage::getStoreConfig('file_processing/ifile_ftp/username'),
                        'password'  => Mage::getStoreConfig('file_processing/ifile_ftp/password'),
                        'timeout'   => Mage::getStoreConfig('file_processing/ifile_ftp/timeout')
                    )
                );
                //change directory.
                $sftpDumpFile->cd(Mage::getStoreConfig('file_processing/ifile_ftp/file_location'));
                //get the content of the specified directory
                $directory_content_array    =    $sftpDumpFile->ls();

                print "\n Test directory: \n";
                print $sftpDumpFile->pwd();
                print "\n";
                print "\n test remote ls array: \n";
                print var_dump($directory_content_array);
                print "\n";
                //Get the content of the specified directory and then loop through to grab the documents to transfer locally and then remove them from the ftp server.
                foreach($directory_content_array as $item):

                    print "\n For Each: \n";
                    print $item['text'];
                    print "\n";

                    if (($item['text'] != '.') && ($item['text'] != '..') && (!strstr($item['text'],'processed')) && (strtolower($item['text']) != '.ds_store')):
                        if($item['text']):
                            if (strstr($item['text'],'_FILE_')):
                                try{
                                    $sftpDumpFile->read($item['text'],Mage::getBaseDir('var').'/import/'.$item['text']);
                                    die(); //Check to see if file is copied locally
                                    print "\n Reading: \n";
                                    print $sftpDumpFile->read($item['text'],Mage::getBaseDir('var').'/import/'.$item['text']);
                                    print "\n";
                                $sftpDumpFile->rm($item['id']);
                            endif;
                        endif;
                    endif;
                endforeach;
            } catch(Exception $e) {
                Mage::log('There was a processing error when transferring files from the FTP server.');
                Mage::logException($e);   
            }
```

If I run the script that connects to the test server the file I'm importing is now in my var/import directory.

If I run the script connecting to our remote SFTP account the file has not been moved to to our local var/import folder. Due to excessive printing(i'm running the script by triggering cron from console) I'm fairly sure the point of failure is this line:

```
$sftpDumpFile->read($item['text'],Mage::getBaseDir('var').'/import/'.$item['text']);
```

However, I'm not sure what the problem is and I'm getting very little help from the remote SFTP host.

In the past we've found that these issues are typically permissions or passive FTP issues. Since we're connecting SFTP, which establishes a single direct TCP connection, I think it's safe to say it probably isn't a passive FTP issue.

The remote SFTP account folder permissions are 700 and the file permissions are 600.

I replicated these permissions on our test server. Again, the script ran as expected.

Any troubleshooting ideas or thoughts?

***Update***
So it looks like replacing my Die(); with:

```
die(print_r($sftpDumpFile,true));
```

Has given me some very useful information:

```
[channel_open_failure_reasons] => Array
            (
                [1] => NET_SSH2_OPEN_ADMINISTRATIVELY_PROHIBITED
            )

        [terminal_modes] => Array
            (
                [0] => NET_SSH2_TTY_OP_END
            )
 [sftp_errors] => Array
            (
                [0] => NET_SFTP_STATUS_FAILURE: The message  [/import/filename] is not extractable!
            )

    )
```

A little googling around the error "NET_SSH2_OPEN_ADMINISTRATIVELY_PROHIBITED" is showing that this script may require the remote host to enable

```
AllowTCPForwarding yes
```

I highly doubt they'll be willing to do so. Is there a way to bypass the need for this?

***Update 2***
It looks like the following error appears even on successful transfers:

```
NET_SSH2_OPEN_ADMINISTRATIVELY_PROHIBITED
```

The only error that seems to be returned is:

```
NET_SFTP_STATUS_FAILURE: The message  [/import/filename] is not extractable!
```